# Using egrep to find lines that have 5-6 Upper Case letters. (but not more than 6)

Tags: linux, bash, unix, grep

First off, this is homework and unfortunately I have to use egrep (and not with -w or anything of the like).

I need my grep to return lines that have exactly 5 or 6 upper case letters.

Doing `egrep [A-Z]{5,6} .filename` returns 5 and 6 letter words, but also unfortunately also more letter words than that.

So I for example in this list:

```
ASK
roger ROBERT gulliver
tom THOMAS
JONATHAN moore
MELISSA tenant
```

I need it to return only ROBERT and THOMAS.

Comment: +1 all around, I wish I had more opportunity to use regexp's in my work life!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
egrep "^[^A-Z]*[A-Z]{5,6}[^A-Z]*$" .filename
```

Comment: Update: you are explicitly talking about no more than 7 uppercase letters. I'm not sure what you want with lowercase. My regexp does allow xROBERTx, while cYrus' regexp refuses it.

Answer (score 2):

Try with:

```
egrep '^[A-Z]{5,6}$'
```

where `^` and `$` match beginning and ending of the line, respectively.

Comment: Forgot to mention that the words in the list were not at the start or end of the lines, my bad.  Geeklab below had the right formula for the alternate version.  Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

Yet another version

a) limited to 5 or 6 Upper Cases in the word;

b) word can have unlimited lower case, plus the '-' and the apostrophe: '

c) uses the \b word edge character (zero-width);

This finds more than your list, (which you would want), and follows all limitations you state.  This may result in more than you bargained for, since it also permits any number of lower-case letters **between** the upper-case letters:

> "\b[a-z'-]*([A-Z][a-z'-]*){5,6}\b"

Will find:
**awesome JET-LI**

**Jane DeSILVA**

But not:
**old MacDONALD**